# Disable startup sound when turning on my Macbook M1

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, startup, sound-volume

I am looking for a way to turn off that useless sound every time I open / turn on my Macbook.
This is a Macbook Air (M1, 2020) currently on Big Sur 11.0.1

I already tried something without success:

- this script:  https://github.com/matteoacrossi/nobootsound
- the simple command  "sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80"

Someone can help ???
Thank you !

Comment: sudo nvram StartupMute=%01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a checkbox for it in System preferences:

https://www.howtogeek.com/700255/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-startup-sound-on-mac/

Comment: Ouch ! It was so easy ! You just need to know it is there !
Thank you !